# Autoconf/Automake: How to avoid passing the "check" option to AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS

Tags: c++, autoconf, automake

I'm using Autoconf to build my c++ project. It uses third party code which is also built with the help of Autoconf/Automake. So in my `configure.ac` I've got the following line:

```
AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS([subdirectoryname])
```

Everything works fine, but I also use the feature to let tests be automatically made if `make check` is executed - which is done by the third party code as well. Because these tests take a while it's annoying to execute them each time I want to test my own code. So is there any way to avoid that the `check` option is passed to the subdirectory's `Makefile`?

**Update:** Overriding `check-recursive` does not seem to be an option, as my top-level Makefile.am looks (more or less) like this:

```
SUBDIRS=library src
```

So disabling checking on this level would also disable the checking inside my `src` folder. And that's not what I want to achieve. I just want to disable the checking in the `library` directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overriding `check-recursive` in your `Makefile.am` should work:

```
check-recursive:
     @true
```

or, if you only wanted to check in a specific directory:

```
check-recursive:
     $(MAKE) -C src check
```

Comment: That's not so easy I think. I added some information about my Makefile.am above.

Comment: Great! Your second option did the job.

Answer (score 0):

according to the autoconf manual, it will execute a configure.gnu script in the subdirectory if it finds one. Theoretically that could be a script which adds a --disable-tests or similar option to a call to ./configure

That said, I've yet to get this to work on a project of my own. :-/

Comment: Sounds interesting. If you got something, let me know.

Comment: If you are able and going to modify the subdirectory, better put a `GNUmakefile` in the library directory that does nothing on check and calls Makefile for everything else.

Comment: I am not able to modify the contents of the library directory (imported via svn external and so on...). That's the whole clue: I want to configure this from above. Making changes to the library directory would be easy.